# NetBSD 9.3 - NFS Setup /etc/exports

Tags: nfs, netbsd

I am trying to setup NFS, i have run into some problems with regards to /etc/exports

When the content of my /etc/exports file is this:

```
/data1 192.168.1.213(rw)
```

I get this from showmount -e 192.168.1.245

```
client$ showmount -e 192.168.1.245
Exports list on 192.168.1.245:
client$
```

But when i have this in my /etc/exports file:

```
/data1 -alldirs -network 192.168.1.245 -mask 255.255.255.0
/data2 -alldirs -network 192.168.1.245 -mask 255.255.255.0
```

from here: https://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-net-services.html

I get this from showmount -e 192.168.1.245

```
client$ showmount -e 192.168.1.245
Exports list on 192.168.1.245:
/data2                             192.168.1.245 
/data1                             192.168.1.245
```

I can mount data1 and data2 on my client machine (also NetBSD 9.3) but I get permission denied when I try to copy files, mkdir etc

Reading this:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_file_systems/exporting-nfs-shares_managing-file-systems
i understand that this is the general format of /etc/exports:

```
export host(options)
```

What i would like to achieve is the following: every machine on the network (192.168.1.*) regardless of what user connects can mount whatever mount point NFS on my server (192.168.1.245) offers with read and write privileges

Reading the RedHat documentation I understand that it´s something like:

```
/data1 host(rw,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=100)
```

gid and uid is set to match my user named user (non-root)

But I am not sure what to do from here.

**Update**
The accepted answer solved the problem, I am now facing permission issues: [NetBSD 9.3 - NFS Permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/1144946/netbsd-9-3-nfs-permissions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `-mapall=1000:100` to the lines in the `/etc/exports` file you crafted based on the NetBSD Guide.

The documentation for the `exports` file can be viewed on the NetBSD system by running `man exports`, or on the web at https://man.netbsd.org/NetBSD-9.3/exports.5

Comment: Great, thanks, i really appreciate you taking the time to help with this.

I have altered my /etc/exports:

/data1 -alldirs -mapall=1000:100 -network 192.168.1.245 -mask 255.255.255.0
/data2 -alldirs -mapall=1000:100 -network 192.168.1.245 -mask 255.255.255.0

When i try to mount using:

localhost$ mount 192.168.1.245:/data1 ./storage/

I get:

WARNING: autoselecting nfs based on : or @ in the device name is deprecated!
WARNING: This behaviour will be removed in a future release
mount_nfs: bad MNT RPC: RPC: Authentication error; why = Client credential too weak

Comment: Glad that I was able to help. It would nice if you would [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as it sounds like it fixed the issue for you.

Comment: The error you now see is likely caused by trying to run `mount` as a regular user instead of running it as *root*. Have a look at this thread about [RPC Authentication Error when mounting NFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261541/rpc-authentication-error-when-mounting-nfs) for more details.

If it is still an issue, please raise it as its own question instead of asking in comments.